# Decoding a binary signal

Tags: c, binary, protocols, reverse-engineering, gpio

I'm reading the following binary signal off a gpio pin on my Raspberry Pi (it's the output from a weather station).

The 1st column is binary high or binary low. The second column is how long (seconds) it spends in the state.

How can I convert this signal to hexadecimal?!

```
...
0 14.929292
1 0.002127
0 0.006867
1 0.001393
0 0.005303
1 0.001274
0 0.006126
1 0.001361
0 0.007541
1 0.001417
0 0.005062
1 0.001474
0 0.005119
1 0.001565
0 0.004906
1 0.001587
0 0.004916
1 0.002031
0 0.006007
1 0.001479
0 0.003678
1 0.001485
0 0.000994
1 0.004142
0 0.000865
1 0.006277
0 0.003858
1 0.001288
0 0.001028
1 0.001468
0 0.000945
1 0.004138
0 0.003327
1 0.001303
0 0.001174
1 0.001318
0 0.001017
1 0.001510
0 0.001485
1 0.001080
0 0.001907
1 0.002782
0 0.001083
1 0.002012
0 0.000712
1 0.003984
0 0.001785
1 0.001291
0 0.003149
1 0.001185
0 0.001020
1 0.001719
0 0.000993
1 0.003965
0 0.001157
1 0.001346
0 0.001762
1 0.001353
0 0.003219
1 0.001090
0 0.001106
1 0.001475
0 0.001160
1 0.001079
0 0.003874
1 0.001387
0 0.001015
1 0.001168
0 0.001092
1 0.001336
0 0.002504
1 0.001466
0 0.006063
1 0.001391
0 0.001196
1 0.001460
0 0.001082
1 0.001237
0 0.005049
1 0.001654
0 0.004914
1 0.001410
0 0.002722
1 0.001601
0 47.818081
1 0.001452
0 0.007532
1 0.001438
0 0.007975
1 0.001494
0 0.003077
1 0.002131
0 0.003056
1 0.001254
0 0.002685
1 0.001372
0 0.005003
1 0.002051
0 0.006997
1 0.001608
0 0.004868
1 0.001524
0 0.002524
1 0.001397
0 0.003103
1 0.001211
0 0.002434
1 0.001328
0 0.003475
1 0.001469
0 0.003672
1 0.001384
0 0.003847
1 0.001101
0 0.001133
1 0.001352
0 0.003504
1 0.002133
0 0.003257
1 0.001070
0 0.001182
1 0.001511
0 0.003301
1 0.001482
0 0.003779
1 0.001210
0 0.001099
1 0.001396
0 0.001127
1 0.001433
0 0.001697
1 0.001434
0 0.003132
1 0.001175
0 0.001754
1 0.001520
0 0.002905
1 0.001425
0 0.003625
1 0.001155
0 0.001036
1 0.001469
0 0.001041
1 0.001422
0 0.001251
1 0.001275
0 0.003414
1 0.001446
0 0.001734
1 0.001653
0 0.000435
1 0.002349
0 0.000974
1 0.005346
0 0.003247
1 0.001265
0 0.001192
1 0.001213
0 0.001404
1 0.001349
0 0.000963
1 0.003732
0 0.001186
1 0.001220
0 0.002529
1 0.001357
0 0.002573
1 0.001700
0 0.001158
1 0.001058
0 0.002571
1 0.001314
0 0.001164
1 0.001364
0 0.124659
1 0.001485
0 0.007492
1 0.002176
0 0.006881
1 0.002083
0 0.005526
1 0.001351
0 0.005029
1 0.001528
0 0.001726
1 0.001366
0 0.002089
1 0.001258
0 0.002579
1 0.001463
0 0.001262
1 0.001487
0 0.000975
1 0.003736
0 0.002321
1 0.002073
0 0.004412
1 0.001433
0 0.002619
1 0.001390
0 0.002817
1 0.001201
0 0.003475
1 0.001512
0 0.000906
1 0.003958
0 0.003492
1 0.001581
0 0.000985
1 0.004103
0 0.001370
1 0.001046
0 0.001162
1 0.001534
0 0.001080
1 0.001510
0 0.003077
1 0.002124
0 0.003046
1 0.001293
0 0.003908
1 0.001406
0 0.001002
1 0.001109
0 0.001524
1 0.001009
0 0.001347
1 0.001448
0 0.000950
1 0.003651
0 0.001133
1 0.002038
0 0.002838
1 0.001991
0 0.002866
1 0.001291
0 0.003824
1 0.001191
0 0.001163
1 0.001447
0 0.000970
1 0.004059
0 0.000972
1 0.006388
0 0.001252
1 0.001262
0 0.001345
1 0.001329
0 0.004930
1 0.001273
0 0.003556
1 0.001570
0 0.003431
1 0.001550
0 0.001256
1 0.001461
0 0.001098
1 0.001005
0 0.002555
1 0.001503
0 0.005044
1 0.002070
0 0.004427
1 0.001499
...
```

As you can see, it's zero for ~48 seconds and then fires a load of 1's and 0's and goes back to zero again.

I need to figure out the protocol. I can't tell what it is. The only information I do have is that the current temperature is 21 degrees celcius, wind speed is zero and wind direction is null. Any insight is greatly appreciated,

[image: plot of binary data]

Above is a plot of some binary data for two different transmissions.

Comment: Why can't you look up the protocol being used?

Comment: It's a Chinese weather station. I'm reverse engineering it.

Comment: Plot that using those seconds increments, you'll probably see the pattern.

Comment: @WilliamMorris I'm at the max the processor can give me. Programming in C.

Comment: I would guess it's serial UART, just need to guess the baudrate

Comment: I disagree. It looks like a PWM signal to me.

Comment: Have you actually tried reading it on a serial pin?  Because there are all sorts of sampling rate issues that can potentially make your measurements invalid.  Posting your sampling code would be helpful in eliminating that possibility.  Also helpful would be if you posted more information on the weather station, like its model and the identity of the chip you're reading from.

Comment: Also, if the station's manual is in chinese you could potentially post a link here hoping for someone fluent in chinese to help (not me). Or copy paste it into translate.google.com and hope it works out something.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Weather station is an "N96GY" http://www.maplin.co.uk/usb-touchscreen-wireless-weather-forecaster-228825. I'm intercepting the signal using a QAM-RX3-433 http://mt.rsdelivers.com/product/quasar/qam-rx3-433/am-superhet-receiver-433mhz-thru-hole/7424484.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As @NikolaiNFetissov says, plot the periods you measured.  But plot several, one above the other, starting with the 1st interval after the 48 second break.

So you will have:

```
A (21C) _____|----------|_____|-----|_____|-----

B (24C) ______|---------|_____|-----------|__________

Clock   _____|-----|_____|-----|_____|-----|_____|-----

etc
```

I would measure several cycles with different conditions (eg different temperatures but the same wind/direction), plot them and then see if you can see which parts of the pattern change. It would help if you knew the sampling rate and plotted that too.  You say it is at the fastest possible, but I imagine there you are counting clock ticks or something - or how else are you determining the number of seconds?

Edit:

How to plot that? I was imagining a piece of squared-paper and a pencil :-)  As for a program, my only (brief) experience was with gnuplot. For that you'd have to create lists of coordinates from your intervals, so:

```
1 0.006
0 0.002
1 0.005
0 0.001
```

might be turned into:

```
x,     y
0.0,   1
0.006, 1
0.006, 0
0.008, 0
0.008, 1
0.013, 1
0.013, 0
0.014, 0

etc
```

My guess is that in the time it would take to install and learn to use gnuplot and to create the coordinates, you could plot the data on paper and figure out the code.  But to me, the clock rate is key... (sorry to go on about it ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Can you suggest a program to plot these kinds of diagrams? I tried LibreOffice Calc to no avail...

Comment: Yes, the clock rate is key. I'll have to figure that out. I'm hoping to connect to a logic analyser tomorrow.